# jquery slider - bringing images back to the start position

Tags: jquery, css

I'm newbie and I've build a query slider (horizontal) with different images heights.

```
.slide-img {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
     -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    overflow-y:auto;
    float:left;
    clear:none; 
}
```

It works. But when I scroll down image, slide to next image, and then go back to previous image, the position does not reset to top. How can I manage this. Thank you!

Comment: We're going to have to see somemarkup in order to be able to help you here.

Comment: If you could add a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), that would help a ton.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I've added JSFiddle, but couldn't get it to work. Html, css and js are inside. The link to fiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/digimus/zEv6a/2/